# Generating pdfmake header & footer from HTML: incomplete rendering

Tags: javascript, html, pdf-generation, pdfmake

I'm working on a browser app that should export a PDF. This PDF must have user-defined headers and footers. These headers and footers are stored in a database as strings and are fetched with an API call.

I am using pdfmake and htmltopdfmake for this. I am parsing these HTML strings like this:

```js
exportReportToPDF (tableData, tableKeyMap, reportSettings, reportTitle) {
      /* Style constants */
      const blue = '#044e99'
      const marginArray = [40, 5, 0, 10]
      const documentDefinition = {}
      const rawHTMLStyles = {
        h1: {
          fontSize: 16,
          color: blue,
          margin: marginArray
        },
        h2: {
          fontSize: 14,
          color: blue,
          margin: marginArray
        },
        h3: {
          fontSize: 12,
          color: blue,
          margin: marginArray
        },
        p: {
          fontSize: 8,
          margin: marginArray
        },
        hr: {
          margin: [0, 0, 0, 0]
        }

      }

      /* Generate header and footer */
      if (reportSettings.header && reportSettings.footer) {
        const header = htmlToPdfmake(reportSettings.header, {
          defaultStyles: rawHTMLStyles,
          imagesByReference: true
        })
        const footer = htmlToPdfmake(reportSettings.footer, {
          defaultStyles: rawHTMLStyles,
          imagesByReference: true
        })
        documentDefinition.header = header.content
        documentDefinition.footer = footer.content
      }

      /* irrelevant code redacted  */

      pdfMake.createPdf(documentDefinition).open()
    },
```

This isn't working well. If i pass this as `reportSettings` to the function, the header displays incorrectly. The `<h1>` appears, but the `<h2>` doesn't.

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "Prueba",
  "header": "<h1>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</h1><h2>consectetur adipiscing elit</h2>",
  "footer": "<p>Lorem ipsum 2021</p>",
  "created": "2021-07-06T15:21:10.864259Z",
  "updated": "2021-07-06T15:21:10.864358Z",
  "creator": 1
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How should I make this HTML render?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/1399)! Increasing the document's `pageMargins` makes the hidden lines appear. It seems like the body of the document hides the header and footer as if it had a higher z-index.

Like this:

```js
exportReportToPDF (tableData, tableKeyMap, reportSettings, reportTitle) {
      const documentDefinition = {
        pageMargins: [40, 80, 40, 80]
      }

     /* ... */

      pdfMake.createPdf(documentDefinition).open()
    },
```